# How do I get my video to float left and my paragraph to be on the right of the video?

Tags: html, css

I want to simply get my video to be on the right and to have a paragraph explaining the video on the left and then do the same thing under that video and so on, so far I tried doing it but it doesn't seem to look right. How would I go about doing so??

[Here is jsfiddle of what I tried:](http://jsfiddle.net/FA49J/)

```
  <div style="display: inline-block">
    <div class="vidOne">
     <iframe style="float: left"              src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries?list=PLFE2CE09D83EE3E28"
            width="100px" height="100px" frameborder="0"></iframe>
       <p >The is a paragraph that should go right of video 1</p>
    </div>
        <br>
   <div class="vidTwo">
      <iframe style="float: left" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries?list=PLFE2CE09D83EE3E28"
                width="100px" height="100px" frameborder="0"></iframe>
       <p>The is a paragraph that should go right of video 1</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

This is my aim:[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
style="float: left"
```

to

```
style="clear:left; float: left"
```

Note that you may want to also add some top margin to the div containers to space them apart more vertically.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/FA49J/1/)**

Comment: when I increase the size of the video to 560X315 the text goes under the videos if though there room for the text to go right [Heres an example:](http://jsfiddle.net/FA49J/2/), How do I go about making the text go right?

Comment: Float the paragraphs left too.